# Custom formatter does not work if specified in logging.properties

Tags: java, java.util.logging

I have custom Formatter and which I wanted to usein my application to fromat the log before it get actually logged.

My formatter looks like...

```
package com.mycomp.logger;

import java.text.MessageFormat;

import java.util.Date; 

import java.util.logging.Formatter; 

import java.util.logging.LogRecord;  

public class BnaLogFormatter extends Formatter {

    private static final DateFormat format 
        = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
    private static final String lineSep = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    public BnaLogFormatter() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public String format(LogRecord record) {
        System.out.println("#### Inside custom formatter ####");
        String transactionId = WsUtils.getTransactionIdFromSoapHeader();
        String threadName = "[Thread=" + Thread.currentThread().getName() 
                + "] [transactionId=" + transactionId + "] ";
        String message = record.getMessage();
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder()
        .append(format.format(new Date(record.getMillis())))
        .append(" ").append(record.getSourceClassName());
        output.append(threadName); 
        output.append(record.getLevel()).append(": ");
        output.append(record.getMessage());
        if (record.getParameters() != null) {
            output.append(StringUtils.toString(record.getParameters()));
        }

        output.append(' ').append(lineSep);
        return output.toString();
    }
}
```

In my logging.properties, I have an entry like this:

```
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=com.mycomp.logger.BnaLogFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level=OFF
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=logs/ena.log
```

Then I restarted my tomcat server, but still I am unable to to my customized log messages. Whats wrong with my code here?

Answer (score 0):

Set the logging level of the FileHandler to ALL.

```
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=com.mycomp.logger.BnaLogFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level=ALL
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=logs/ena.log
```